# Orthonormal Functions

Tags: integration

Given the two functions, $$ \sqrt {\frac1L} $$ and $$ \sqrt \frac2L\sin\left({ \pi x \over L}\right)$$ I would like to show that they are orthonormal to each other, i.e. using the inner product $$ \int_0^L \sqrt {\frac1L}\sqrt \frac2L\sin\left({ \pi x \over L}\right) dx  $$ that this equals to zero. It's a relatively staright forward integral, yet I can't get the answer as zero. The answer that I'm getting is $ 2 \sqrt {2} \over \pi $, which is clearly not what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: $\sqrt{\frac{1}{L}}$ is a constant... The inner product as stated can be $0$ only if the second function integral is $0$ on the interval, which is clearly not the case since the function is everywhere positive on the interval...

Comment: The value you found for the integral is correct. You should probably be integrating over $[-L,L]$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int\limits_0^L \sqrt{\frac{1}{L}}\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}
\sin \frac{\pi x}{L} dx
= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{L} \left[ -\frac{L}{\pi} \cos \frac{\pi x}{L} \right]_0^L
= \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\pi}
$$